# Appropriate ways to show scores in relation to population percentile

Tags: r, excel, graph, comparison, spss

I have a data set with 8 variables and just over 300 observations (participants). These observations are randomly divided into 10 groups. Each participant perform the same set of tasks.

For each group, I want to draw a graph which illustrates how well they performs in terms of where their mean scores land in the overall percentile.

I did some googling and found the graph below. This is a graph for one group of participants and each bar represents a single task.
The performance labels are produced by dividing the overall score (of each task) into 5 percentile groups (10%, 20%, 40%, 20%, 10%) respectively.

Is there a way to draw this in either R, SPSS, or Excel?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you could do something like this :

```
a=c(0.1,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.9)
# a containes the result per category in a vector

barplot(a, names.arg=c("Cat1", "Cat2", 
"Cat3","Cat4","Cat5"),horiz=TRUE,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,6.5))

# add the vertical lines
abline(v=c(0.25,0.5,0.75),col='red')

# add the text
text(0.1, y =6.3, labels = 'Low')
text(0.4, y =6.3, labels = 'Average')
text(0.6, y =6.3, labels = 'High')
text(0.85, y =6.3, labels = 'Very high')
```

The output would look like this :[image: Results of the test per category]

Pretty basic but you could customize it further if you want to.

Edit : add code to compute quantile over the different categories. I will assume that you have an R dataframe with 2 columns, 1 cointaining the result name "col" and one containing the category named category.

Then this code will work :

```
# df is the dataframe in which your data are stored
all_categories = unique(df$category)

N=length(all_categories)
results_category=rep(0,N)
# q is the percentile you have to compute 0.5 is the median
q_wanted=0.5

for (i in (1:N)){
  results_category[i] = quantile(x=df$col[df$category==all_categories[i]],prob=q_wanted)
}

barplot(results_category, 
names.arg=all_categories,horiz=TRUE,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,5))
abline(v=c(0.25,0.5,0.75),col='red')
text(0.1, y =4, labels = 'Low')
text(0.4, y =4, labels = 'Average')
text(0.6, y =4, labels = 'High')
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want !! Now how do I calculate where exactly the tip of each bar should land? I need to calculate where each score should land within its sample quantiles. I did some research and found the ecdf function might help but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: ecdf is necessary to compute the empirical distribution function. I think you just have to compute percentiles per category. You could for that use an R data.frame combined to the quantiles function and correct filters except if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I'm new to R so forgive me for asking.
Let's say I have an item which has score ranging from 0 to 20. After data collection and analysis, I have a median of 15. I want to find out where subject A lands given his score is 13.

Comment: To be a little more precise, let's say there is only one variable, with 300 observations. Observations are grouped into groups of 30, so there are 10 groups. I want to tell on what percentile each group's mean falls into.

Comment: Edited the answer I can not provide much more details

Comment: one more thing, do you know whether there are any packages which makes bars like the ones above? And what are they call ?

Comment: I do not and I really doubt that recent R library would do so as it is very old fashioned and imo not very readable.